# Power Surge Damage to Refrigerator

Tags: electrical, refrigerator, compressor

our house had several power surges last week that damaged a few of our major appliances including our indoor and outdoor refrigerators. Today, a repair person told us that our indoor fridge is leaking freon. Could that be tied to compressor damage from the surge?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to imagine a surge causing a leak .However, a surge can damage the motor and that can often require replacing the compressor. Modern refrigerators usually have some kind of electrical protection to prevent motor damage. Several years ago I had a GE that was damaged by a surge; In that case the "start" capacitor was burned out but it was outside the compressor so I could replace it for several dollars. That could be your situation.

Comment: If it is the cap, then the repair person is lying about a leak.

Comment: There could be a leak for some other reason but I don't know how a surge could cause it